# SignalR in Angular and NET Core, trying to refresh connections lists

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Please bare with me I am trying to learn SingalR, I can't even see my tab names anymore and most of the tutorials just do `Client.All.SendAsync` and they got their clicks for their websites.

I wanna make a chat app and I followed some documentation from Microsoft for the backend which works but I don't get it for the client.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://localhost:7005/chat/')
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

this.hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection started!');

      this.hubConnection.invoke('GetAllActiveConnections').then((result: any) => {
        this.connections = result;
    });
  }) 
  .catch((err:any) => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

  this.hubConnection.on('SendMessage', (nick: string, receivedMessage: string) => {
    this.messages.push(receivedMessage);
  });

  this.hubConnection.onclose(() => {
    console.log('connection closed')
  });
}

public sendMessage(): void {
  this.hubConnection
    .invoke('SendMessage', this.nick, this.message)
    .catch((err:any) => console.error(err));
}
```

This is basically all the code I have and I wanna break it down for some explanations.

what is confusing for me is that some methods from `HubConnection` are either a `Promise` or `void` and I feel stuck I don't know how to communicate with the backend.

What I am trying to achieve here is displaying a list of all connection ids and later I will do it with usernames but when I do a new connection or I disconnect I don't know how to refresh the list or push into the list since `onClose()` doesn't do what I think it should do, and `start()` is a `Promise`, which doesn't push new connections the way I am trying there.

Do I need to create a controller and call methods in the `Hub`? but then again how do I react in Angular when the user disconnects, I am assuming OnDisconnectAsync gets called in the backend but how do I tell that to the client? Since the client has no Obserable to react on changes.

The `Hub` looks like this

```
private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage", user, message);
}

public string GetConnectionId() => Context.ConnectionId;

public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    _connections.Add("bob", Context.ConnectionId);

    return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
{
    _connections.Remove("bob", Context.ConnectionId);

    return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetAllActiveConnections()
{
    return _connections.GetConnections("bob");
}
```

And I have no controller because I don't know why I would need it.

I think helping me solving this problem with connection list would be a tremendous help to understand how to communicate between angular signalr and the backend hub or a controller.
All I want is to push a new connection in the list when that happens and remove it when user closes his browser tab and I have no way of doing it and I don't know how should I do it with a controller since OnDisconnectAsync gets called anyways.

I know I am asking a lot and thank you for your time

Comment: The thing is an identifier that defines the client name is bound to the client-side. Hubs `OnConnectedAsync` is not aware of the client state as it is called right after the successful connection. So you need to register your client after the successful connection and the method that you call for registration should map the client name to the client connection. And I would suggest moving the connection operations into a singleton service because you will disconnect as soon as you navigate away from the component that you define the connection.

Comment: I had to read a few times what you said. So I called `await Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateConnectionsList", _connections.GetConnections("bob"));` in both connect and disconnect and then in the client `this.hubConnection.on('UpdateConnectionsList', (connections) => this.connections = connections; });`. So I always need to keep in mind this Identifier thing, e.g: `UpdateConnectionsList`, this is what makes the real-time happening between backend and client, this is was the first day of signalr, I am sure there is more of that but today was connectionlist, next actual users, next one-to-one chat

Comment: If you want you can write an answer and get some free points

Comment: Good luck with your journey and glad to help.